# 3D Camera for small objects

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

I am working on a project in which I have to extract 3D geometry of small textured things (think, a small rock or a grain of rice).

I guess normal 3D cameras won't work for this, since they seem to be made for larger objects. Also, the objects I am describing are quite featureless, so I guess something

How can I go about extracting 3D geometry of something like a grain of rice?